# Find null values from table and replace it with space - sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, replace, find

I am having sqlite database.

In some columns I am having null values.

I want to replace null values with space..

Is there any query for this?

Please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`IFNULL`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull). In a query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(mycolumn, ' ') FROM mytable
```

Or to change the data in the table:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = IFNULL(mycolumn, ' ')
```

Alternatively:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = ' ' WHERE mycolumn IS NULL
```